# IOTA "one-click-tangle" via docker linux containers - ERROR 1

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nodes, private-network, iota

I am trying to run a private tangle on my computer through linux docker containers.
Therefore I followed the guide over at https://wiki.iota.org/chrysalis-docs/tutorials/one_click_private_tangle
Every step succeeded up until we tried to execute

```
./private_tangle.sh install
```

This reports

> Error 1

as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: error screenshot]

We do net get any further information, is anyone familiar with this error, or has any clue how to get some more information on the error so that we can at least have a clue where to look?

Some further information:

- After executing `docker ps -a` we see that not a single container is running.
- I am running on a windows 10 machine
- I execute the commands from within ubuntu (version 20.04)
- Ubuntu, docker-desktop and docker-desktop-data are all running WSL2
- Docker integration with ubuntu is activated
- I thought the error could maybe come from no hornet node initially being installed, so I installed a hornet node successfully, according the guide that https://wiki.iota.org/chrysalis-docs/tutorials/one_click_private_tangle. This changed nothing to the Error.
- The version of docker and docker-compose are compliant with the requirements

If any more details are needed to help me solve this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I used the documentation (https://wiki.iota.org/chrysalis-docs/tutorials/one_click_private_tangle) to install these containers on my local ubuntu 18.04.

My docker version is:  20.10.12

And docker-compose version is:  1.29.2

By following the steps of the tutorial I managed to successfully start all of the containers without trouble.

My guess here would be that the permission of the 'private-tangle.sh' are not correct or that there is permission problem on the docker level.

You should start with checking the permission level of the private-tangle.sh script by using `$ls -l`

Here is my output `-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben ben 9413 Jan 11 11:28 private-tangle.sh`

It could also be due to the docker rights if you have to use sudo when executing a docker command it will give some troubles when executing the script.

You need to add yourself to a docker group to be able to run docker commands without sudo. You can do this by running `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`  with damiaan-vh as `$user`.

Solution from source https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70665394/edit

Suggesting to downgrade ubuntu version to 18.04 for more stable version.

For reinstalling the docker and docker-compose programs follow this documentations
(docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ )
(docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ )